# Data disappears from the page when viewed

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a list of registers when I want to see them, they disappear when there are more than 20 of them before I scroll down the page and reach the end, after which they disappear. In this case, only one error appears in the console.

An error that appears in the browser console when viewing registers.

```
This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. 
This is a no-op. Please check the code for the RegistersList component.
```

---

list.js

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect }                     from 'react-redux'
import { Link }                        from 'react-router';
import * as utils                      from '../../utils';
import moment                          from 'moment';
import { bindActionCreators }          from 'redux'
import InfiniteScroll                  from 'react-infinite-scroller';
import { index as fetchRegisters }     from '../../actions/registers';

var page = 0

@connect(
  state => ({
    currentFeatures: state.features,
    registers: state.registers.items
  }),
  dispatch => ({
    actions: bindActionCreators({
      fetchRegisters
    }, dispatch)
  })
)
export default class RegistersList extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    registers: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    articles: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    counterparties: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    handleDestroy: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { hasMoreItems: true };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    const { props } = this

    if (props.current !== newProps.current) {
      this.setState({ hasMoreItems: true })
      page = 0
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    page = 0
  }

  fetchRegistersOnScroll() {
    const { actions, current, dispatch } = this.props
    page++

    actions.fetchRegisters(current, page)
      .then(res => {
        dispatch({ type: 'REGISTER/SCROLL', payload: res.data });

        if (res.data.items.length < 20)
          this.setState({ hasMoreItems: false })
      })
  }

  render() {
    const { registers, articles, counterparties, handleDestroy, currentFeatures } = this.props;

    const registersList = registers.map((register, i) => {
      const article = articles.find(a => a.id === register.article_id) || {}
      const typeName = article.type == "Cost" ? 'cost' : 'revenue';
      const counterparty = counterparties.find(c => c.id === register.counterparty_id) || {}
      const client = counterparties.find(c => c.id === register.client_id) || {}
      const manager = counterparties.find(c => c.id === register.sales_manager_id) || {}

      return(
        <tr className="register-table" key={i}>
          <td>{ moment(register.date).format("DD-MM-YYYY") }</td>
          <td>
            {article.title}
            <span className={`register-title-label ${typeName}`}>
              &nbsp;({typeName})
            </span>
          </td>

          { (currentFeatures && currentFeatures.sales) ?
            <td>{ client.name }</td>
          : null }

          { (currentFeatures && currentFeatures.sales) ?
            <td>{ manager.name }</td>
          : null }

          <td>{counterparty ? counterparty.name : '-'}</td>
          <td>{register.value}</td>
          <td><div className="register-note">{register.note}</div></td>
          <td>
            <div className="btn-group btns-hidden" >
               <Link
                  to={`/registers/${register.id}/edit`}
                  className="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
                >
                  <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
              </Link>
              <button
                className="btn btn-sm btn-danger"
                onClick={handleDestroy.bind(this, register.id)}
              >
                <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </button>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      )
    })

    if (registers.length) {
      return (
        <InfiniteScroll
          pageStart={0}
          loadMore={this.fetchRegistersOnScroll.bind(this)}
          hasMore={this.state.hasMoreItems}
          loader={<tr className="loader" key={0}><td><b>Loading ...</b></td></tr>}
          element={'tbody'}
        >
          { registersList }
        </InfiniteScroll>
      )
    }

    return(
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td rowSpan="6">
            There are no registers...
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    );
  }
}
```

---

registers.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import cookie from 'react-cookie';

const API_URL = `${window.location.origin}/api/v1/registers`;

export function index(params, page) {
  return function(dispatch, getState) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let headers = {}
      headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${cookie.load('token')}`
      headers['workspace-id'] = getState().workspaces.app.current.id
      params.page = page

      axios.get(API_URL, { params, headers })
        .then(res => {
          dispatch({ type: 'REGISTER/FETCH', payload: res.data });
          resolve(res)
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.error("error: ", e);
          reject(e)
        })
    })
  }
}

export function show(id){
  return function(dispatch, getState) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let headers = {}
      headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${cookie.load('token')}`
      headers['workspace-id'] = getState().workspaces.app.current.id

      axios.get(`${API_URL}/${id}`, { headers: headers })
        .then(res => {
          dispatch({ type: 'REGISTER/SHOW', payload: res.data });
          resolve(res)
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.error("error: ", e);
          reject(e)
        })
    })
  }
}

export function create(register){
  return function(dispatch, getState) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let headers = {}
      headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${cookie.load('token')}`
      headers['workspace-id'] = getState().workspaces.app.current.id
      let body = {register: register}

      axios.post(API_URL, body, { headers: headers })
        .then(res => {
          dispatch({ type: 'REGISTER/CREATE', payload: res.data });
          resolve(res)
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.error(e);
          reject(e)
        })
    })
  }
}

export function update(register){
  return function(dispatch, getState) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let headers = {}
      headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${cookie.load('token')}`
      headers['workspace-id'] = getState().workspaces.app.current.id
      let body = {register: register.register}

      axios.patch(`${API_URL}/${register.id}`, body, { headers: headers })
        .then(res => {
          resolve(res)
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.error("error: ", e);
          reject(e)
        })
    })
  }
}

export function destroy(id){
  return function(dispatch, getState) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let headers = {}
      headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${cookie.load('token')}`
      headers['workspace-id'] = getState().workspaces.app.current.id

      axios.delete(`${API_URL}/${id}`, { headers: headers })
        .then(res => {
          dispatch({ type: 'REGISTER/DELETE', payload: id });
          resolve(res)
        })
        .catch(id => {
          console.error("error", id);
          reject(id)
        })
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: try binding handlers in constructor  `this.fetchRegistersOnScroll=this.fetchRegistersOnScroll.bind(this)` - avoid binding in render

Comment: It did not help me.

Comment: Error still exists? Try to render data directly, w/o `InfiniteScroll`

Comment: In short, I removed the page++ of fetchRegistersOnScroll(), then everything started to work, or rather all the registers are displayed. But now the problem is that some of them are displayed twice, how to fix it?

Comment: You're passing some data from parent (page 0?) - is it needed? You can call first fetch from `componentDidMount` keeping state(current page, starting index for next fetches) in one component. Check parameters in requests/network tab - fetches probably has overlapping ranges.

Answer (score 1):

Following your comments, you already solved the data disappears from the page but now you have data duplicacy which can be solved by modifying the fetchRegisterOnScroll Function. As InfiniteScroll may call loadMore function again and again so we need to check that is it being called or not.

Below is the code snippet which might help.

```
fetchRegistersOnScroll() {
    if (this.state.isFetching) return;         // checking request has already been called or not.
    const { actions, current, dispatch } = this.props

    this.setState({ isFetching: true });
    actions.fetchRegisters(current, page)
      .then(res => {
        dispatch({ type: 'REGISTER/SCROLL', payload: res.data });

        if (res.data.items.length < 20)
          this.setState({ hasMoreItems: false, isFetching: false })
        else this.setState({ isFetching: true })
      })
  }
```

I think it will help. Thanks!!

Comment: I liked your answer, but alas, it does not solve my problem, I continue to receive the same error.

Comment: Can you please share the code of the two actions you are dispatching basically REGISTER/FETCH action and REGISTER/SCROLL actions ?