# setState(...) Can only update a mounted or mounting component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a page with registers, when I just go to it, they load if there are a lot of them, but if I go to the bottom of the page, they all disappear, and this error will reappear.

An error occurred in the console when the list of registers was received.

> Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting
>   component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted
>   component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the
>   RegistersList component.

The supposed portion of the code to which the error goes.

```
  fetchRegistersOnScroll() {
    const { actions, current, dispatch } = this.props
    page++

    actions.fetchRegisters(current, page)
      .then(res => {
        dispatch({ type: 'REGISTER/SCROLL', payload: res.data });

        if (res.data.items.length < 20)
          this.setState({ hasMoreItems: false })
      })
  }
```

Comment: As the error says, your components are being unmounted before the response returns, so it's trying to call `setState()` on an unmounted component.

Comment: How can I fix this?

Comment: Well that depends what's causing them to unmount. There's no info in your question about the components' mounting logic so I can't really say. Either way, those are 2 separate issues. First is why your components are unmounting when they shouldn't, second is you don't handle the case of what if the component is unmounted when the request returns. For the second issue, you can track whether a component is mounted with a simple boolean property `this.mounted=true` in `componentDidMount` and `this.mounted=false` in `componentWillUnmount`

Comment: is the outer component being unmounted?  (ie. the one with `fetchRegistersOnScroll`)?  It will help if you share as much context as possible.  It seems likely that the outer component is failing, hence everything disappearing.  Also - maybe share how your registering the event.

Comment: I had a similar question, there is all the code. If you can please see.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51821420/data-disappears-from-the-page-when-viewed

Comment: When checking for a duplicate with help - if (register.id == page) it helped me. But only now I get an error - ReferenceError: register is not defined. How to fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think your component remounts again when your are trying to update the redux store. So I suggest you to setState before the dispatch action. Also, in the other link of the post where you posted the complete code, you are making two redux dispatch actions simultaneously. I don't know what are they suppose to do exactly but I think it would be better if you could make them in one single request.

```
if (res.data.items.length < 20)
    this.setState({ hasMoreItems: false })
```

Alternatively, you can call setState in the componentWillReceiveProps too. That can also help you to remove the error.

I hope it helps. Thanks!!